# Was ist ein Rutzelfutz?

Tags: meaning

Im Zuge einer Debatte über Sinn und Unsinn von Wortneuschöpfungen suchte ich nach Beispielen für (deutsche) Wörter, die es nicht gibt.

Im Glauben

> Rutzelfutz

sei ein solches Wort, strengte ich gleichwohl eine Überprüfung mithilfe verschiedener Suchmaschinen an und musste dabei feststellen, dass ich mich getäuscht hatte. Das Wort ist - wenn auch selten - durchaus auffindbar und somit in Gebrauch.

Was aber bedeutet es?

(In etablierten Nachschlagewerken finde ich es nicht.)

Comment: Kannst Du vielleicht Deine Treffer hier mit aufführen/verlinken? (zumindest teilweise, falls es zu viele sind...)

Comment: @arsak  Normalerweise täte ich das. Hier hatte ich überlegt, dass es die Meinungsbildung vielleicht verfälschen könnte, denn bekanntlich geben die marktüblichen Suchmaschinen jedermann andere Ergebnisse. Aber gut, als Kompromiss hier im Kommentar: Es handelt sich um einen Chat-Konversation, und ein Beteiligter sagt: "Wie schön es ist im gemütlichen Bett zu liegen anstatt noch einen Rutzelfutz zu trinken". (Quelle: https://ask.fm/tillbarschtipan.)

Comment: Verstehe. Also wenn _ich_ google, bekomme ich genau zwei Ergebnisse, beide verweisen auf den von Dir verlinkten Chat. Das bringt mich zu dem Schluss, das jener "@tillbarschtipan" Dein Alter Ego ist, und Du mit dieser Frage Deine eigene Wortneuschöpfung promoten willst- Problem solved ;)

Comment: Aber mal ernsthaft: Wenn ich mir die Treffer (auch aus anderen Suchmaschinen) so ansehe, kommt mir der Verdacht, dass bestimmte Wortneuschöpfungen wahrscheinlicher sind als andere und daher von verschiedenen Menschen erfunden werden. Ich bin gespannt auf die Antworten!

Comment: Wie bist Du denn überhaupt erst auf das Wort gekommen?

Comment: @infinitezero - Ich verwende das Wort "Rutzelfutz" seit vielen Jahren an verschiedenen Stellen, wo man ein inhaltsleeres Unsinnswort, das deutsch klingt, brauchen kann. Darum war ich nun überrascht, es hier noch andernorts in Gebrauch zu finden.

Comment: @arsak  - Schlaue Vermutung, aber: Nein, ich bin nicht dieser Till Barschtian. Ich war ehrlich überrascht, das Wort hier in konkretem Gebrauch zu finden, und zwar durchaus nicht inhaltsleer sondern ja wohl im Sinne irgend eines Getränks... ?

Answer (score 4):

Funde für Rutzelfutz:

- der von dir verlinkte Post, in dem das Wort für ein Getränk verwendet wird (https://ask.fm/tillbarschtipan)
- ein Benutzername auf der Spieleplattform roblox.com

Den Namen würde ich direkt streichen, da er nicht auf den Sinn des Wortes schließen lässt.
Er kann auch zufällig gewählt sein.

Wenn das Wort *Rutzelfutz* in der Schriftgeschichte nur einmal vorkommt (und diese Diskussion ändert an dem Status nichts), wäre das ein [Hapaxlegomenon](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hapaxlegomenon) (zur Bedeutung von Hapaxlegomena, s. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon)), oder es würde zumindest eines sein, sobald Deutsch nicht mehr gesprochen wird.

Dass es sich um ein *allgemein bekanntes* »inhaltsleeres Unsinnswort, das deutsch klingt« handelt, das mir bloß unbekannt ist, schließe ich aus:
Dann gäbe es mehr Treffer im Internet.

Wenn es mehr Treffer für die Verwendung als Getränkebezeichnung gäbe, hätte ich auf einen lokalen Schnaps, Likör o. ä. getippt, doch die Beweislage liegt anders.
Es gibt allerdings einen Schnaps, in Celle produziert, der ähnlich klingt: [Ratzeputz](http://www.ratzeputz-celle.de/).
Die lautliche Ähnlichkeit lässt zumindest die Vermutung zu, dass *Rutzelfutz* von Ratzeputz abgeleitet ist.

Ebenso lässt sich die Ähnlichkeit mit dem bekannten Wort [Rachenputzer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rachenputzer) nicht leugnen, doch die Dreisilbigkeit von *Rachenputzer* klingt schon zu entfernt, um eine direkte Ableitung vermuten zu lassen.

Die Interpretation der Wortbestandteile *rutz* und *futz*, wie sie im Grimm beschrieben sind, überlasse ich dem Fragesteller:

> RUTZ, interjection, im ablautspiel zu ritz und ratz, schnelle, reiszende bewegung bezeichnend. […] auch als subst., schneller stosz, ruck.
>   FUTZE, verkürzt futz, f. eins mit dem weitaus geläufigeren fotz, dessen o nur brechung des u ist.